# Change the delimiter in multiple CSV files from same folder and write them into a new folder

Tags: windows, python-3.x, csv, delimiter

I am a newbie programmer in python and I am trying to read multiple csv files from a folder, replace the delimiter for all the csv files with 'tab' delimiter and then output these files into a new folder with replaced delimiter. So far I am stuck at the beginning.
Here is the code that I started using, this is working for a single file. But am not able to work with multiple files in same folder.

```
print("\nWrite same CSV File with different string(Replace ',' with tab delimiter)")

with open('Names.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    with open('Names_new.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\r')

        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Please can someone point out some tips?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show us sample input, the code you've written to solve the problem, and sample output. It would probably be best if you were to read the stackoverflow help file.

Comment: Please put that code into your question so that it's more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code in your question does what you want. However, here's how to embed it in more code that will read the csv files from a specified folder for processing.

- `listdir` takes `input_folder` and yields a list of all of the files in that folder.
- I loop through that list and process only those files whose names end with '.csv'.

---

```
from os import listdir
import csv

input_folder = 'catalyst/'

for file_name in listdir(input_folder):
    if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
        print ('---> processing input file: ', file_name)
        with open(input_folder + file_name,'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            out_file_name = file_name[:-3]+'_new.csv'
            print ('   creating', out_file_name )
            with open(input_folder + out_file_name, 'w') as new_file:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\r')
                for line in csv_reader:
                    csv_writer.writerow(line)
```